# Database which was set up for logshipping is dropped

Tags: sql-server

I dropped an old unused database. Then I found it was set up to be the source database of a logshipping setups. And there are a lot failing jobs in our job running status report now.
How to remove the logshipping settings after the database is already removed?

Comment: How exactly are the status jobs failing? Are you sure they aren't just hard-coded to check the status of the logs for individual databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix alert issues use database: msdb and

First of all find out details on Primary Server by executing following..

PRIMARY SEVERE

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.log_shipping_monitor_primary
where primary_database like 'CHANGE_DB_NAME%'


SELECT * FROM dbo.log_shipping_primary_databases
where primary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'

SELECT * FROM dbo.log_shipping_primary_secondaries
where secondary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'
```

Once verifies DB names execute

```
delete FROM dbo.log_shipping_monitor_primary
where primary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'


delete FROM dbo.log_shipping_primary_databases
where primary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'

delete FROM dbo.log_shipping_primary_secondaries
where secondary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'
```

Follow same steps on SECONDARY SERVER

SECONDARY

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary
where secondary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'


SELECT * FROM dbo.log_shipping_secondary_databases
where secondary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[log_shipping_monitor_primary]
where primary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'
```

and once confirmed delete details from table by executing following....

```
delete FROM dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary
where secondary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'


delete FROM dbo.log_shipping_secondary_databases
where secondary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'

delete FROM [dbo].[log_shipping_monitor_primary]
where primary_database like 'DB_NAME_HERE%'
```

Hope this will help you to clear your unnecessary notifications from msdb database. It happens when you do not clear log-shipping clearly or in your case database dropped.

Comment: Thanks. It seems a couple of jobs were created in the SQL Agent. Should these jobs be removed manually? Or anything else need to be done for removing these jobs?

Comment: You can execute above queries and delete entries from tables in madb and you can manually remove SAL Agent Jobs by deleting them.

Comment: There are two jobs: `LSAlert_ServerName` and `LSBackup_DBName`. Is it safe manually remove both if there is no logshipping set on the server? Or `LSAlert_Server` should be kept if there are other logshipping on the server?

Comment: You can remove LSAlert_ServerName and LSBackup_DBName job manually as there is no DB left on instance for LS. LSAlert_ServerName  will be recreate once you have LS setup again first time. LSAlert_ServerName  is one job per server.